# Extracting a particular type of string from a text file using nltk

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

i want to extract all the fish types in wikipedia page and print those fishes(i copied the content to a text file ) . I used pos tag and then used chunker to extract the fish types .But my output contains other unwanted data ,here is the code i implemented

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.chunk.regexp import RegexpParser
#opening the file and reading 
fp = open('C:\\Temp\\fishdata.txt','r')
text = fp.read()
lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
sentence_re = r'''(?x)      # set flag to allow verbose regexps
      ([A-Z])(\.[A-Z])+\.?  # abbreviations, e.g. U.S.A.
    | \w+(-\w+)*            # words with optional internal hyphens
    | \$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?      # currency and percentages, e.g. $12.40, 82%
    | \.\.\.                # ellipsis
    | [][.,;"'?():-_`]      # these are separate tokens
'''
chunker = RegexpParser(r'''
 NP:
{<NNP><'fish'>}

 ''')
stpwords = stopwords.words('english')
lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
toks = nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, sentence_re)
postoks = nltk.tag.pos_tag(toks)
sent=chunker.parse(postoks)
print sent
```

Output i got

```
wikipedia
armored 
fish
ray-finned
fish
jelly
fish 
constucutive
then
oragn
```

Output required

```
armored 
fish
jelly
fish
bony
fish
```

The above is just a small part of the output but i need whats required in 2nd output
The input is wikipedia page -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish which i copied into text file .

Comment: hi! some input sample data along with the output data that is unwanted may help. also - we don't need your whole program. it would be easier for us to take a look if you zero into the lines of code that are not working as expected!

Comment: i have updated what i require and the problem is in chunker segment ,it is producing more nouns than required along with term 'fish'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
fish_words = set()
fish_types = set()
for i in wn.all_synsets():
  # if 'fish' exist in a word.
  x = [j for j in i.lemma_names if "fish" in j]
  fish_words.update(x)
  # if a word ends with 'fish'
  y = [j for j in i.lemma_names if "fish" in j[-4:]]
  fish_types.update(y)

print fish_types
print [i.replace("_"," ")[:-4].strip() for i in fish_types]
```

I'm not sure what kind of fish you're looking for but the above methods should give you all the fish you need as long as you depend on WordNetLemmatizer.

Comment: i dont want to extract from wordnet ,  i need to extract all fish types i.e extract names of fishes that are in wikipedia fish page ,using regular expresion and pos tag . Basically need to take the term fish and find the nouns before it and after it and display those

Comment: use the same idea in the code. (a) find words with 'fish' in it and (b) find words that ends with 'fish'. Otherwise you have to train a classification model to find what is a fish. http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html

Comment: thanks for the info,i used the above code to extract all the fish type from wikipedia fish page, i just extracted all the tags with NNP,JJ and NN and put in a list.Then i used your code to get all fish names.Ty again :)